# urllib.request.urlopen Error

Tags: python, request

Hi I'm new to python and I'm using version 3.6.2

I can't seem to even code the most basic of lines, as seen below. I would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a SSL Certificate error. When you're making the request, set the parameter `verify=False`

Sample code:

```
import requests as rq

response = rq.get("https://google.com", verify=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I still get errors using your method.



>>> import requests as rq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests as rq
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

>>> response = rq.get("https://google.com", veryify=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    response = rq.get("https://google.com", veryify=False)
NameError: name 'rq' is not defined

Comment: This is a generally a very bad idea, it removes all the protection that HTTPS is meant to give against an active attacker, so anyone on the same network as you can intercept all of your traffic and see the contents, while to the remote endpoint it looks like the connection can be trusted.

Comment: So is there a way around this error or am I unable to access the web using python? I'm very new and this is the first time trying it.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError occurs when the package isn't installed. Use `pip install requests`

Comment: Do I need to download the requests package ? Is so where from and where shall I put the folder ? Thanks very much for the help

Comment: Open command prompt and check if pip is installed with `pip --version`. Then run the command `pip install requests` to install the requests library. Then run the code in my answer. However, you're better off checking the SSL problem in your firewall.

Comment: Legend !! I'll give it a go and thanks for all the help. Side note but will the process be the same if I wanted to use Atom !